# Pandoc batch conversion

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple **bash script** in order to batch convert Markdown files via `pandoc` and it is working for me. But I have the feeling the code is dirty. Could you help me improve it?

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -r out; mkdir out

for f in src/*.md
do
    filename=$(basename "$f")
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    echo "Processing $filename"
    pandoc "$f" -o "out/$filename.epub"
    pandoc "$f" -o "out/$filename.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## overall and good stuff

This is pretty good.  I definitely wouldn't call the code dirty.  Good stuff:

- The indentation is good
- putting double quotes around variable substitutions is a best practice
- using `$()` for command substitution is the best practice also
- the `#!` is good
- providing meaningful output to the user is nice
- the variable names are ok

## suggestions

- I get putting `rm -r out; mkdir out` on one line sounds good because they're related, but it doesn't help the readability here.  If you want to tie them together so that the `mkdir` doesn't run unless `rm` succeeds then you could do `rm -r out && mkdir out`.  Otherwise I'd put them on two lines.  Breaking up things with blank lines, as you've already done, is enough to make clear which things belong together.
- `for f in src/*.md` certainly works most of the time, but will break if there's any white space in a filename.  Fixing this involves [using find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321757/79839).  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9499/79839) is part of a duped question, but it may be a bit easier to follow.
- Having `f` and `filename` as variables is a bit confusing.  For something this short it is pretty harmless which is why I said they were ok above.  If you want to tweak this `f` might make more sense as `fullpath` or `fqfn`.  And `filename` might be better as `basename` or `base`.
- add `if ! which pandoc`... near the top to catch if `pandoc` is missing.

```
if ! which pandoc > /dev/null; then
        echo you need pandoc
        exit 1
fi
```

## further reading

- [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is handy.  You can run it locally or in your CI pipeline or manually paste something into their site.
- [bash best practices by Yaroslav Tkachenko](https://sap1ens.com/blog/2017/07/01/bash-scripting-best-practices/) is a nice quick read on bash best practices.
- [google shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html) is even more in-depth with best practices.
- [env is good for portability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613044/2002471) but this is rarely an issue with `bash`.  It might become a more current problem if Apple dumps bash after [adopting zsh as the default](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features).

Comment: "for f in src/*.md certainly works most of the time, but will break if there's any white space in a filename." -- nope, not true, this is perfectly fine!

Comment: Don't use `which` unless is also a buitlin to the shell that you're using. It does not know builtins, functions and alias.